# How can I ggplot a logistic function correctly using predict or inv.logit?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, predict

I have some observations that I have used to determine death rates based various concentrations of a chemical. I have weighted these rates based on the number of observations underlying them, and fit them to a glm (binomial(link=logit)) model. I have been unsuccessfully trying to display a plot of this model in ggplot including original observations (size = weight), model fitting line, and confidence interval, without luck. I can get a simple plot() to work, but then I can't display the other graphics I need. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

```
#data:
C <- data.frame("region" = c("r29","r31","r2325","r25","r2526", "r26"),"conc" = c(755.3189,1689.6680,1781.8450,1902.8830,2052.1133,4248.7832),"nr_dead" = c(1,1,18,44,170,27), "nr_survived" = c(2,3,29,1370,1910,107),"death_rate" = c(0.33333333,0.25000000,0.38297872,0.03111740,0.08173077
,0.20149254))
C$tot_obsv <- (C$nr_survived+C$nr_dead)
#glm model:
C_glm <- glm(cbind(nr_dead, nr_survived) ~ conc, data = C, family = "binomial")
#ggplot line is incorrect:
ggplot(C_glm, aes(C$conc,C$death_rate, size = C$tot_obsv)) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.5)) + theme_bw() + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "glm", mapping = aes(weight = C$tot_obsv))

#correct plot of inv.logit = logistic function (1/(1+exp(-x)))
plot(inv.logit(-3.797+0.0005751*(0:6700)))

#using predict function works, but doesn't display confidence interval or nice point sizes:
x_conc <-seq (750, 6700, 1)
y_death_rate <- predict.glm(C_glm, list(conc=x_conc), type="response")
plot(C$conc, C$death_rate, pch = 10, lwd = 3, cex = C$tot_obsv/300, ylim = c(0, 0.5), xlim = c(0,7000), xlab = "conc", ylab = "death rate")
lines(x_conc, y_death_rate, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

Basically, I am trying to plot the glm predicted logistic curve, observation weights, and confidence interval using ggplot, but can only get the curve to display correctly using plot().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building up on [@IceCreamToucan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6762755/icecreamtoucan) answer

```
tibble(
  x_conc = c(seq(750, 6700, 1), C$conc), 
  y_death_rate = predict.glm(C_glm, list(conc = x_conc), type = "response")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(C, by = c('x_conc' = 'conc')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x_conc, y = y_death_rate)) +
    #geom_line(aes(size = 0.8)) + commented out as binomial smooth does this
    geom_point(aes(y = death_rate, size = tot_obsv)) + binomial_smooth()
```

of course we will need to define the function `binomial_smooth`
this is taken from:https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

```
binomial_smooth <- function(...) {
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), ...)
}
```

[image: plot with smoothing based on glm and conf. interval shading]

Comment: This is great, thanks to you both! Lessons learned: tibble, left_join, and binomial_smooth. Oh, and I should have installed tidyverse long ago... more fun to play when you have the right tools :P

Answer (score 0):

You can include the realized values of the regressor(s) in your `predict` function, and then add a `geom_point` using only the data from values realized by the regressor(s). If you use `size = tot_obs` it will only plot points where that column is non-missing, i.e. only the values in `C`.

```
tibble(
  x_conc = c(seq(750, 6700, 1), C$conc), 
  y_death_rate = predict.glm(C_glm, list(conc = x_conc), type = "response")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(C, by = c('x_conc' = 'conc')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x_conc, y = y_death_rate)) +
    geom_line(aes(size = 0.8)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = death_rate, size = tot_obsv))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks great! Now how can I get my confidence band to display? (sorry for novice questions!)

Comment: just need to add this to code above ` + binomial_smooth()`. `binomial_smooth` is defined as `binomial_smooth <- function(...) {
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), ...)
}` from here https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Comment: @infominer I would be interested if you want to post an answer with that method. To be honest tat's what I tried first but I couldn't figure it out. I think that would be the preferred method rather than manually using `predict`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but if I just add `+ binomial_smooth()` the prediction line looks different than the one in my answer

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I came across this and had the same issue, the predict() curve is different than binomial_smooth().  In my case, I traced the issue to the use of `scale_x_log10()`.  My predict() curve is adjusted appropriately when I do a log transform, but the binomial_smooth() one is not.  When I don't log transform the lines match perfectly.

Comment: This issue is also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63077268/5322644, but I couldn't get the proposed solution to work.