# Differences between glm predictions and geom_smooth() using same glm

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, glm

I am trying to reproduce someone else's work using a probit model. Unfortunately, I don't have much information about their methods, only their starting data and a plot of their model.

When I plot the data in ggplot and fit a line using `geom_smooth(method = "glm", ...)`, I am able to reproduce the prior work. However, when I try to fit (what I think is) an identical model outside of ggplot using `glm()`, I get different predictions. I feel like I making some silly mistake, but I can't quite pin it down.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(x = c(0.006, 0.014, 0.025, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.5),
             y = c(0.4,   0.733, 0.875, 1,    1,    1,   1))


probit_model <- glm(y ~ x, data = df, family = quasibinomial(link = "probit"))

df <- df %>%
  add_row(x = 0.001, y = NA) %>%  # To underline that these models are different
  mutate(y_pred = predict(probit_model, newdata = ., type = "response"))


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y_pred), color = "red", lwd = 1) +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, color = "blue",
              method = "glm", fullrange = TRUE,
              method.args = list(family = quasibinomial(link = "probit"))) +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.001, 1))
```

And here is the plot it produces. Note that the blue line and the red line describe different fits. I believe they *should* be the same (ignoring the piecewise nature of the red line), given they use the same model and data.

[image: Plot]

I've read quite a few threads in the process of troubleshooting, and many responses suggest that `geom_smooth()` is not a replacement for modelling. Broadly, I agree. That said, I am explicitly trying to figure out what `geom_smooth()` is doing here, and then reproduce it outside of ggplot.

My questions are:

Why are these two models different? How is `geom_smooth()` calling `glm()`? How can I call `glm()` myself to reproduce the model that `geom_smooth()` is using?

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are extrapolating. The data don't support any predictions lower than 0.06, so the model understandably fails there. But maybe the glm in the geom_smooth is fortifying the prediction by expanding it out to a super-low x value, and the constraints dictate that it must asymptote at 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The models are actually the same. You can see this if you set, say, `xlim(0, 0.1)` and remove `scale_x_log10`. Then you'll see the fits coincide.

I think the behavior you're seeing is because `scale_x_log10` performs the axis transformation *before* any statistical summaries (such as `geom_smooth`). So, when you run `scale_x_log10`, `geom_smooth` is effectively fitting the model `y ~ log10(x)`, rather than `y ~ x`. If you use `coord_trans(x="log10")` instead of `scale_x_log10`, you'll also see that the models coincide, since `coord_trans` does the transformation *after* any statistical summaries.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the issue! If I change my model to: `probit_model <- glm(y ~ log10(x), data = df, family = quasibinomial(link = "probit"))` or use `coord_trans(x = "log10")` as you suggested, the models match up.